# Angular Stopping and Clearing an interval

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I have this in a component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
        console.log('still running...');
      }, 1000);
    }

  stop() {
    clearInterval();
  }
```

How can I make it stop and clear so I no longer see any console.logs in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the ID of the interval you want to clear:

```
intervalID;

ngOnInit() {
  this.intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('still running...');
  }, 1000);
}

stop() {
  clearInterval(intervalID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should store the reference returned from `setInterval` and pass it to `clearInterval` as parameter.

```
  intervalRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.intervalRef = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('still running...');
    }, 1000);
  }

  stop() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalRef);
  }
```

you can try [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tr2cwp)